# Retrofit error: JSON document not fully consumed

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I'm stock using retrofit for few days, I'm trying to parse the response to my POJO class, initially the error was set lenient to true which I did and ended up here, no related questions here seem to solving my problem

JSON Response from server:

```json
{
"error": false,
"message": "Login successful",
"student": {
    "fullname": "Idris Muhammad",
    "matric": "u14/fns/csc/066",
    "department": "computer science",
    "gender": "male",
    "email": "mail4idris@gmail.com",
    "phone": "08065468035",
    "level": 100,
    "faculty": "Applied Science and Technology"}
}
```

```
POJO Class
public class LoginResponse {

    @SerializedName("error")
    private boolean error;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("student")
    private Student student;


    public LoginResponse(boolean error, String message, Student student) {
        this.error = error;
        this.message = message;
        this.student = student;
    }

    public boolean isError() {
        return error;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
}

Restrift Interface

       @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<LoginResponse> studentLogin(
            @Field("matric") String matric,
            @Field("password") String password
    );

My OnclickListener

         btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


              
                Call<LoginResponse> call = RetroClient.getInstance().getAPI().studentLogin(id.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString() );
                call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                        LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
                        if (loginResponse.isError()){
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }else {

                            String matnum []= id.getText().toString().split("/");

                            SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());

                            sharedPrefManager.storeUserType(SharedPrefManager.USER_TYPE_STUDENT);
                            sharedPrefManager.storeDepartment(matnum[2]);
                            sharedPrefManager.storeFaculty(matnum[1]);
                            sharedPrefManager.storeLevel(loginResponse.getStudent().getLevel());
                            sharedPrefManager.storeActivation(true);
                            sharedPrefManager.storeUserType(SharedPrefManager.USER_TYPE_STUDENT);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

              
            }
        });
```

This is my Student class

```
    public class Student {
    @SerializedName("fullname")
    private String fullname;

    @SerializedName("matric")
    private String matric;

    @SerializedName("department")
    private String department;

    @SerializedName("gender")
    private String gender;

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("phone")
    private String phone;

    @SerializedName("level")
    private String level;

    @SerializedName("faculty")
    private String faculty;

    public Student(String fullname, String matric, String department, String gender, String email, String phone, String level, String faculty) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.matric = matric;
        this.department = department;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.level = level;
        this.faculty = faculty;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public String getMatric() {
        return matric;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public String getFaculty() {
        return faculty;
    }
}
```

my logcat

```
2018-11-29 14:12:59.244 4775-4775/com.ietech.ibbumobile E/RETROFIT: JSON document was not fully consumed.
```

Comment: please provide your error log and the way you build and send your request that fails.

Comment: @idris You can post your code here like POJO class, code where you are using retrofit and the error in your logcat.

Comment: pl add your json response and logcat and other code that you try.

Comment: i have added what you asked for @Distra and others

Comment: @idris please also provide the logcat where the error is displayed, otherwise we're still not really able to help you since we don't know when and where your error occurs. Could you please also provide the code of your Student class?

Comment: logcat and student pojo class as been added @Distra

Comment: @idrismuhammad one line logcat is not enough to figure out what the problem is. Please post the full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?