# How get JSON as string using retrofit

Tags: android, json, rest, api, retrofit2

Please i'm new to retrofit and I've been stuck for weeks now, i tried getting my response as POJO class and end up with this error "Json document was not fully consumed", I've searched and also ask this question here and no one was able to help get out of this

Now i want to get my JSON as string from retrofit so i can do the conversion manually myself to my POJO class and dont know how to get the response JSON as string

Please i need your help I've been stuck with this for 3 weeks

Comment: Can you post the JSON and some code regarding the request?

Comment: Here is a link to my previous with all my json and pjo class https://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515784/retrofit-error-json-document-not-fully-consumed&ved=2ahUKEwiI-Znd6ojfAhXLNcAKHWn-CPoQrAIoADAAegQICBAH&usg=AOvVaw0yGVEHl8I-Ude3zwzZKui6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit error: JSON document not fully consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515784/retrofit-error-json-document-not-fully-consumed)

Comment: @dudi Can you help answer that question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just set the response type as String

```
@GET("api/offers")
Call<String> loadOffers();
```

instead of

```
@GET("api/offers")
Call<List<Offer>> loadOffers();
```

add this in your build.gradle  file

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
```

and in `public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {`

add these lines at the end of the function. the important part is the convert factories

```
if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
```

then you can fetch your data as JSON string

```
MyApi service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(MyApi.class);


        Call<String> callTypes = service.loadOffers();

        callTypes.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response {                    
                String urJson  = response.body() ; 
               //  DO UR STUFF HERE
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Diaa Saada's

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you in getting the response as string.

```
public interface RetrofitService{
        @GET("/users")
        Call<ResponseBody> listRepos();//function to call api
    }

    RetrofitService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> result = service.listRepos(username);
    result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        try {
            System.out.println(response.body().string());//convert reponse to string
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Hope this will work for you too.

Comment: Calling the string method on responseBody object isnt giving me my json string

Answer (score 0):

Get the gson lib, it will do it for you. You Just have to creat an object which fit the json, and the lib will set the data in your object with you Json.